# Jquery .on("click") to a span isn't working in Firefox but works in Firefox Dev

Tags: jquery, firefox

So I have an interesting case where I have a table with options to click a button to delete a row.

```js
var each_row = $("<div>").addClass("multiple-group-fields");
var remove_button = $("<button>").addClass("classes").appendTo(each_row);
var delete_icon = $("<span>").addClass("moreClasses");
remove_button.append(delete_icon);

 delete_icon.on("click",{row:each_row}, function(event) {
    alert("clicked");
})

$("body").append(each_row);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Example</p>
</body>
```

```
var remove_button = $("<button>").addClass("myClasses").appendTo(each_row);
var delete_icon = $("<span>").addClass("moreClasses");
remove_button.append(delete_icon);

delete_icon.on("click", {row:row_each}, function(event) {
      alert("clicked");
})
```

but this doesn't seem to work in regular Firefox. In fact, when I hover over the button, the cursor isn't a pointer as well.

However, when I switched over to Firefox Developer Edition, I had no problems with this whatsoever. Is there a different behavior between Firefox Dev and regular old Firefox?

When I inspect the element in *regular* Firefox, I can see that an event is attached to it (my alert()) but it doesn't seem to be triggered here

Would appreciate any insight! Thanks!

Note: This works fine on all other browsers (Chrome, IE, etc). My dev FF is on v66 while my regular FF is on v65

Comment: At the time of this comment FF (normal) is at version 65 but if you [look through the developer releases](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases) they are up to version 67. Which version are you using? You should look through the release notes to see if theres any relavant changes that may explain your issue.

Comment: @crazymatt This is a good point. My (normal) FF is currently on 65 while my FF (Dev) is on 66.0b1

Comment: I'd be very surprised if something as basic as this doesn't work in the production version of Firefox. Millions of web sites would be failing as a result. It's much more likely that you're doing something that blocks it, maybe a plugin, and you don't have that in the developer edition.

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately, I don't think it's something like a plugin because I've tested across other laptops and still haven't been able to find success. Note some of these laptops don't have any plugins installed on (normal) FF. Thanks for your input though :-)

Comment: Can you create an [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Barmar I've added some more context to the original post. Looking between v65 and v66, I don't immediately see how my work is being impacted (but clearly it is) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/66

Comment: That's neither complete nor verifiable. Please create a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) that we can try to run.

Comment: @Barmar I've added a snippet that closely resembles what I'm trying to do. However, it seems to be misbehaving since it doesnt' work even in Chrome

Comment: You're adding the click handler to the span, not the button. The span has zero size, so you can't click on it.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks that seems to have been the issue. Interesting to note that in v66 FF that this won't be an issue

Comment: Why are you passing in `{row:each_row}` as data to the event handler, was that an attempt to delegate?

Comment: Would be tidier to do -> https://jsfiddle.net/d1qvstyo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attaching the click handler to the `<span>` rather than the `<button>`. There's no text in the span, so there's no way to click on it.

Your example works in Chrome if I put something in the span:

```js
var each_row = $("<div>").addClass("multiple-group-fields");
var remove_button = $("<button>").addClass("classes").appendTo(each_row);
var delete_icon = $("<span>").addClass("moreClasses").text("X");
remove_button.append(delete_icon);

 delete_icon.on("click",{row:each_row}, function(event) {
    alert("clicked");
})

$("body").append(each_row);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Example</p>
</body>
```

Or attach the handler to the button instead.

```js
var each_row = $("<div>").addClass("multiple-group-fields");
var remove_button = $("<button>").addClass("classes").appendTo(each_row);
var delete_icon = $("<span>").addClass("moreClasses");
remove_button.append(delete_icon);

 remove_button.on("click",{row:each_row}, function(event) {
    alert("clicked");
})

$("body").append(each_row);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Example</p>
</body>
```

But to make it work in Firefox 65, I need to do *both*. When there's nothing in the span, I can't even see the button in FF.

I suppose the Mozilla developers consider this a bug, and they fixed it in the new version.

```js
var each_row = $("<div>").addClass("multiple-group-fields");
var remove_button = $("<button>").addClass("classes").appendTo(each_row);
var delete_icon = $("<span>").addClass("moreClasses").text("X");
remove_button.append(delete_icon);

 remove_button.on("click",{row:each_row}, function(event) {
    alert("clicked");
})

$("body").append(each_row);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Example</p>
</body>
```